# I can't get mouse out to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this function to prevent the body scrolling when the sidebar is hovered.
The problem is, I can't get the mouseout function to work properly.

```
var currentScroll=0;
function lockscroll(){
    $(window).scrollTop(currentScroll);
}


$(document).ready(function (){

        $(".sidebarholder, .commentswrapper").hover(function (){
            currentScroll=$(window).scrollTop();
            $(window).bind('scroll',lockscroll);

        })  



})
```

My question is, how do I unbind it on the mouseout?

If I do this, it just stops working altogether.

```
    $(".sidebarholder, .commentswrapper").mouseout(function(){
        currentScroll=$(window).scrollTop();
        $(window).unbind('scroll');

    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `hover()` has built in "hover off", which might be helpful:

```
   $(".sidebarholder, .commentswrapper").hover(
     function (){ // hover over
       currentScroll=$(window).scrollTop();
       $(window).bind('scroll',lockscroll);
     },
     function (){ // hover off
       currentScroll=$(window).scrollTop();
       $(window).unbind('scroll',lockscroll);
     }
   )
```

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: This works, but it breaks infinite scrolling as well after you hover off, I can't think why?

Comment: I'm guessing that's because of `unbind('scroll')`, but I'm not sure. Your infinite scrolling may also be bound to 'scroll'. Maybe try: `$(window).unbind('scroll',lockscroll);` instead.

Comment: shouldn't unbinding it effectively reset it?

Comment: You are unbinding anything bound to the 'scroll' event. If infinite scroll is bound to the 'scroll' event, it gets unbound, too. I think you can unbind one specific handler from an event. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972886/how-to-unbind-a-specific-event-handler#3972922

Comment: You're awesome showdev, $(window).unbind('scroll',lockscroll); seems to unbind the specific handler and makes infinite scroll work properly after the hover off.

Comment: Sweet! Glad to hear it works. I edited my answer to include the `unbind` specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".sidebarholder, .commentswrapper").hover(function () {
           currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
           $(window).bind('scroll', lockscroll);

        }, function () {
           currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
           $(window).unbind('scroll');

        })
     })
```