# Unbind challenge

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

I've tried to unbind this :

```
 var foo = $(".js_slide").bind('click' , function () {
  var $contentBlock = $(this).next("li[id^=content_]");

if ($contentBlock.hasClass("is_open")) {
    $contentBlock.animate({
        width: '0%'
    }).removeClass("is_open");
        } 
else {
    // if a content box is open (=> an element with the class .is_open exists), close it
    $(".js_content.is_open").animate({
        width: '0%'
    }).removeClass("is_open");
    $contentBlock.animate({
        width: '45%'        
    }, 500).addClass("is_open");      
}                               
});
```

With the following piece of code ,but someting goes wrong and i can't figure it out what it could be

```
$('.js_slide').unbind('click', foo);
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972886/how-to-unbind-a-specific-event-handler

Comment: Here foo is the matched set of elements returned by ".js_slide" selector. You want to unbind the handler

Answer (score 1):

you should be using on/off rather than bind/unbind as of jquery 1.7.

but for your problem, you are trying to unbind `foo` which isn't a function in your code. You'd need to do something like this:

```
var foo = function () {
    var $contentBlock = $(this).next("li[id^=content_]");

    if ($contentBlock.hasClass("is_open")) {
        $contentBlock.animate({
            width: '0%'
        }).removeClass("is_open");
    } else {
        // if a content box is open (=> an element with the class .is_open exists), close it
        $(".js_content.is_open").animate({
            width: '0%'
        }).removeClass("is_open");
        $contentBlock.animate({
            width: '45%'
        }, 500).addClass("is_open");
    }
}

$(".js_slide").bind('click', foo);
```

then you can unbind like this: `$('.js_slide').unbind('click', foo);`

Comment: it doesn't work,I'm using it with breakpoint.js.All seems to work fine,except the  $('.js_slide').unbind('click', foo); .It's strange

Comment: Are you getting anything in your console? There must be something else because the basic format works well as can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/KSutM/

Comment: i'm using jquery 1.7.2 ,this can be the problem ?

Comment: Are you seeing anything in your console? It's fine in 1.7.2 http://jsfiddle.net/KSutM/1/. There has to be something else wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this...

Basic `click`

```
$('div').on('click.name', function(){
    // do something
});
```

To turn off, use `.off()`

```
$('div').off('click.name');
```

PS : `name` , name whatever you want...

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/GpP9e/

Comment: Well for me doesn't work.I use jQuery 1.7.2 and i'm trying to incorporate the off with breakpoint.js plugin .When the window is at 780 breakpoint i use .off

Comment: Well, 1.7.2 , use bind and unbind :D @Code