# jQuery methods: difference between .submit() vs .trigger('submit')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

jQuery allows to trigger a form submission programmatically via either:

- `$('.js-form-class-hook').submit();`
- `$('.js-form-class-hook').trigger('submit');`

---

Note: My understanding is that `.trigger('submit')` is to `.submit()` what `.on('submit',function(e){});` is to `.submit(function(e){});`. In short `.trigger('submit')` is a more powerfull way than `.submit()` to programmatically submit forms .

I already know some of the difference between `.on('submit',function(e){});` and `.submit(function(e){});`, see my answer on [What's the difference between $(form).submit and $(form).on("submit") in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352251/whats-the-difference-between-form-submit-and-form-onsubmit-in-jquery/25639871#25639871) , I would like to now understand better the role of `.trigger('submit')`.

---

My conclusion: after some research I found out that using `.trigger('submit')` seems to provide the "only" (although very powerful) advantage of allowing **to pass arbitrary data**

---

**Sample usage 1:**

This can for instance be used to differenciate a "**human**" vs "**programmatical**" form submission.

see live demo (click on Run/Clear in the top-right) on [jsbin.com/jivexawixonu/1/edit?html,js,console,output](http://jsbin.com/jivexawixonu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

HTML

```
<form class="js-form-hook-xyz">
   <button>Submit form</button>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
var pleaseConfirmSubmission = function( formElem ){
  // ... some conditions checks
  // if condition met, submit with a flag
  formElem.trigger( "submit" , ['isProgrammaticalSubmission'] );
}


$("body").on("submit", ".js-form-hook-xyz", function(event, isProgrammaticalSubmission) {
  console.log("on form submission: " +  ( isProgrammaticalSubmission || "isHumanAction !" ) );
  if ( !isProgrammaticalSubmission ){ /* JS truthy/falsy value usage */
    event.preventDefault(); /* cancel form submission */
    pleaseConfirmSubmission( $(this) );
  }
});
```

---

**Resources:**

1. [api.jquery.com/submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit)
2. [api.jquery.com/trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger)
3. [api.jquery.com/on](http://api.jquery.com/on)
4. [www.inkling.com/read/jquery-cookbook-cody-lindley-1st/chapter-8/recipe-8-5](http://www.inkling.com/read/jquery-cookbook-cody-lindley-1st/chapter-8/recipe-8-5)

---

Is there any other additional feature provided by `.trigger('submit')` that I missed ?

Or is "allowing to pass arbitrary data" the only advantage of using `.trigger('submit')` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is essentially no different between `submit()` without an argument, and `trigger('submit')`, in fact `submit()` with no arguments will eventually return `trigger()` anyway.

You can prove this by looking at the [jQuery Source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.submit):

**jQuery.fn.submit()**

```
function (data, fn) {
    return arguments.length > 0 ? this.on(name, null, data, fn) : this.trigger(name);
}
```

So, if an argument is passed to `submit()`, `.on('submit'...` will be called, otherwise, `.trigger('submit')` will be called.

`submit()` is pretty much a more human-readable way of calling `trigger('submit')`. There are no special features for either, which one you choose is personal preference.

**Note:** The same goes for [`click()`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.click), [`change()`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.change) etc..

> is "allowing to pass arbitrary data" the only advantage of using .trigger('submit') ?

Unless you consider one less function call an advantage, yes, it is.

Comment: I clarified my question & added this EDIT: "Is there any other additional feature provided by .trigger('submit') that I missed ? Or is "allowing to pass arbitrary data" the only advantage of using .trigger('submit') ?"

Comment: Like @George said, the source code answers that: all the `submit()` function does is call the `trigger('submit')` function. So there is no actual difference.

Comment: @AdrienBe There are no special features for either, which one you choose is personal preference.

Comment: @George Did you actually read the whole question? If yes, don't you think that "pass arbitrary data" is an additional feature!?

Comment: OK, yes, but you already know about that, why would I tell you again? What I meant is, there are no additional features *that you don't know already know about*

Comment: Oh alright, I'll accept your answer then. Could you please add this to your answer (I think I'm not the only who will be confused otherwise) ? thx

Comment: I have added the relevant snippet to the end of the question already (: -- Has that cleared things up for you?