# Submit form by click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, submit

I need to submit a form by clicking a button outside the form.
Here is the simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#buy-button").on("click", function () {
                $("#refresh-form").submit(function () {
                    alert('test');

                });

            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<header>
    header
</header>


<div id="main-div">

</div>

</div>

<div id="navigation-div">
    <form id="refresh-form" action="test.php">
        <button id="map-button">Refresh</button>
    </form>

    <button id="buy-button">Buy</button>

</div>


<footer>
    footer
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the `buy-button` it won't refresh the page. What am I missing?
Suppose that I have a list of buttons inside a form, which of them has `button` as type, if I can successfully submit the form will I get all the values set for each button anyway or will I get only the values of the button which type has been set as `submit`?

Comment: ....$("#refresh-form").submit();

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly use `trigger` like this:

```js
        $(function () {
            $("#buy-button").on("click", function () {
                $("#refresh-form").trigger('submit');
            });
        });
```

From jQuery docs on [submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/):

> Forms can be submitted either by clicking an explicit `<input
>   type="submit">`, `<input type="image">`, or `<button type="submit">`,
>   or by pressing Enter when certain form elements have focus.

It seems to me that manually triggering form submission is a better, workable approach.

Comment: @gaetanoM what do you mean?

Comment: by submitting this way there is no POST request

Comment: @gaetanoM `$("#refresh-form").submit()` STILL does a `trigger`, i.e. `$("#refresh-form").trigger("submit")`. Is there a reason to not explicitly/directly call the trigger? And yes, it submits the form based on the request type (`<form action="POST | GET e.t.c`". Unless I misunderstood what you're saying. Also, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640906/jquery-methods-difference-between-submit-vs-triggersubmit

Comment: Good job. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example
we gonna use ajax

```
<form id="sortContentImagesForm" method="PATCH" action="/">
    <div id="sortContentImages">
    </div>
</form>

<button id="submit-sorted-images" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Submit Sorted
    Images</button>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#submit-sorted-images', function (e) {
        $("#sortContentImagesForm").submit(); // Submit the form
    });


    $(document).on('submit', "#sortContentImagesForm", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');
        var type = form.attr('method');

        $.ajax({
            type: type,
            url: url,
            data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function (payload) {
                toastr.success("Updated Successfully");
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                toastr.error(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want without using JavaScript. If you set the `form` attribute in the [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) tag, it will work as a submit button even if it is placed outside the form:

```
<form id="refresh-form" action="test.php">
    <button id="map-button">Refresh</button>
</form>

<button id="buy-button" form="refresh-form">Buy</button>
```