# Only fire key event when mouse is over object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fire a key event when the mouse is over a certain part of the document and the key is pressed. I tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#main_content").keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 40) {
            alert("button Down");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I expected that wouldnt work but I cant think of another way to do it.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/c57nkb9y/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture key press (or keydown) event on DIV element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149362/capture-key-press-or-keydown-event-on-div-element)

Comment: Yes thats what I thought but it works on $(document). There must be a way to do this.

Comment: So you want to trigger a key event when you hover over the element? Or do you want to trigger it, when you are over it AND press the key?

Comment: I want to trigger it, when I am over it AND press the key.

Comment: Than have a look at the duplicate post. That tells you how you can do it. Normally none `input` fields can't receive key events, so you have to add a `tabindex="x"` attribute to it.

Answer (score 3):

### First solution

Create a variable to **store mouse state**, then update it when mouse **enters** and **leaves**:

```
let mouseIsOver = false
const content = document.getElementById('main_content')

content.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  mouseIsOver = true
})

content.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  mouseIsOver = false
})

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  // When key pressed, check mouseIsOver
  if (mouseIsOver && event.which === 40) {
    alert('Button Down!')
  }
})
```

---

### Second solution

**Attach and Detach** KeyPress listener when mouse **enters** and **leaves**:

```
const content = document.getElementById('main_content')

function keyPressHandler() {
  if (event.which === 40) {
    alert('Button Down!')
  }
}

content.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  document.body.addEventListener('keypress', keyPressHandler)
})

content.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  document.body.removeEventListener('keypress', keyPressHandler)
})
```

Comment: Watch out for the missing quotes around the "body" selector.

Comment: Yes I wanted to pass an object, but forgot to specify document.body.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/), attaching keyboard event listeners to unfocusable elements (like your `#main_content` div) is useless. Instead, I suggest you attach them to the `window` object, or the `body` element.

kube's answer should work fine, but you really don't need to listen to keydown events all the time when you're out of the main div. I propose this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#main_content").mouseover(armKeyEvent);
    $("#main_content").mouseout(shutdownKeyEvent);

    function armKeyEvent() {
        $(window).keydown(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 40) {
                alert("button Down");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    function shutdownKeyEvent() {
        $(window).unbind('keydown');
    }
});
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ej3gxxf/3/).

Comment: I hesitated to post the same approach. However, if you want to go this way you'll have to name your handler functions to prevent all handlers being unbound from `window` when shutdownKeyEvent is called.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972886/how-to-unbind-a-specific-event-handler

Answer (score -1):

You can add your `keypress` event after `mouseenter`, and remove it on `mouseleave`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main_content').mouseenter(function () {
        console.log(this)
        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if (code == 40) {
                alert("button Down");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(document).on("keypress", function () {});
    });
});
```

[UPDATED JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/c57nkb9y/4/)

Comment: i didnt want to fire the alert on hover. It should fire when I am hovering and pressing the down key